# How to serve a HTML + markup string to ReactJS component as a prop?

Tags: javascript, html, json, reactjs

I'm building a simple slide-deck web app that uses a JSON object as a mock database, and I'm rendering the UI via ReactJS components.

Is there a way to store the HTML + markup in the JSON object as a string, pass the string to ReactJS, and then have ReactJS render the HTML elements/markup in a React Component?

Here is an example of the JSON object:

```
{
  "slides": {
    "1":{
      "title":"Introductory Finance",
        "content":"<p>By Raymond Arthur</p>"
        }
  }
}
```

This is the React component:

```
class Body extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div className='body'>
         {this.props.content}    
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

At the moment, if I pass `slides[1].title.content` as a prop to a React Component with a `<div>`, `<p>By Raymond Arthur</p>` is being rendered as text on the screen (i.e. React is not actually creating `<p></p>` elements with text inside them). It's as though React is escaping the `<p>By Raymond Arthur</p>` as a text string instead of recognising the HTML markup/elements.

How can I fix this? How can I store HTML + markup as a string in a JSON object or a database, serve the HTML + markup string to ReactJS, and then get ReactJS to recognise that it is HTML and not just a string?

I have seen other SF threads referencing `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` - is this the only option?

Or ReactDOMServer?

Comment: If you want to avoid dangerouslySetInnerHTML, you can use the package react-html-parser

Comment: Thank you, I'll check out the package,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this you can use **dangerouslySetInnerHTML** attribute something like this.It will wrap your markup which is a object property into specified div Tag below.

```html
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:this.props.content}}></div>
```